# How to setup the lock time in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

My computer locks itself after 2 minutes of no activity.

This is very annoying. How do I increase this time limit, so that it locks after, say, **10 minutes** instead of **2 minutes**?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 7, you right click on your desktop and click "Personalize..." on the menu that pops up, then on Screen Saver in the lower right hand corner of the window that opens. You can then change the value in the box next to "Wait:". Vista is probably similar...

EDIT: I will also add that to disable locking entirely, you can uncheck the "On resume, display logon screen" checkbox next to the time input box.